# android studio layout view not working

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4 for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) and I'm unable to show any content I add to the layout view. I've attached a picture that shows what's happening: [Picture of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhypH.png)

Comment: Click on  red `i` icon in top right of your layout to see whats the problem.

Comment: ![Here it is](https://ibb.co/kDgmOK)